# Hibernate - ManyToOne / OneToOne with Cascade options

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Say I have a `class A`, which has an attribute of `class B`.

I know that there will only ever be one `class B` for every `class A`, so I map this with `OneToOne`. If I mistakenly add the same `class B` to a second `class A`, both `class A`s reference the same `class B` (and so, with `CascadeType.ALL` set, a delete on one of these objects will remove the address referenced by the other). This all makes sense.

However, if I know that there may be multiple (same) instances of `class B` in the database, and I want any `class A`s to use this persisted attribute if it exists, I thought I could map this entity as `ManyToOne` and JPA / hibernate would take care of any necessary checks to see if the data is already in the database (loading and then using equality). It seems this isn't the case.

The `ManyToOne` relationship works in exactly the same way as the `OneToOne` above - i.e. as soon as I delete one of the `class A` objects that references a `class B` object, the 'class B' object gets deleted, too (even if referenced elsewhere). I would expect JPA / hibernate to check this `class B` object isn't referenced by any other `class A` object before deleting (even with `CascadeType.ALL` set - as it is marked up as a `ManyToOne` relationship).

Am I missing something here?

Comment: We really need to see exactly how you have declared the entities and their relationships.

Comment: Can you give a real life example so that we can help you in a better way.

Comment: Sure. A `Person` with reference to `Address`. I've implemented equality in the `Address` object to be line by line equality, as well as the hashcode method. Everything else as above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no simple way to get what you want.

A cascading remove is very simple: if the entity on the cascading side is removed, the entity on the referenced side is also removed. Even if it is referenced by other entities. Well, hopefully, foreign key constraints in the database will prevent the underlying row being deleted, and an exception will be thrown, but the point is that the JPA provider will attempt to remove the entity. It sounds like this is not the behaviour you want, so cascading removal is not for you.

JPA also has a feature called orphan removal, but this has a similar limitation - it can't be used to manage shared objects. You can't even declare it on a `@ManyToOne` relationship.

Rather, i think you will need to handle this deletion manually. Instead of deleting the owning objects directly using the `EntityManager`, encapsulate the deletion in a service object (sometimes called a data access object or a repository) that deletes the object, and then checks to see if its referenced object should also be deleted.

I appreciate that this is awkward. But sadly, as far as i know, this is not something that JPA can automate for you.